# Can NPM show me the age of packages before installing them?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, npm-install

In light of recent malware in existing npm packages, I would like to have a mechanism that lets me do some basic checks before installing new packages or updating existing ones. My main issue are both the packages I install directly, and also the ones I install indirectly.

In general I want to get a list of package-version that npm would install before installing it. More specifically I want the age of the packages that would be installed, so I can generate a warning if any of them is less than a day old.

If I could do that directly with npm, that would be neat, but I'm afraid I need to do some scripting around it.

**specific use case:**

If I executed `npm install react-native-gesture-handler` on 2021-10-22 it would have executed the post-install hook of a malicious version of ua-parser and my computer would have been compromised, which is something I would like to avoid.

When I enter `npm install react-native-gesture-handler --dry-run`, it only tells me which version of react-native-gesture-handler it would have installed, but it would not tell me that it would install a version of ua-parser that was released on that day.

**additional notes:**

- I know that `npm i --dry-run` exists, but it shows only the direct packages.
- I know that `npm list` exists, but it only shows packages after installing (and thus after install-hooks have already done their harm)
- both only show packages version and not their age
- I do not know how I would get a list of packages that would come with a install-hook before installing them
- pointers to alternative ways to deal with malicious npm packages are welcome.
- so far my best solution would be to do "--ignore-scripts" but that would come with it's own set of problems

Comment: the simplest solution i can think of would be to do "npm i && npm list" in a docker-container and then query the api of npm directly to get the age of each package-version. I am hoping for a simpler idea.

Comment: How about npm view? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-view

Comment: same problem as with `npm i --dry-run`. It only shows data for the package itself, not any dependencies.

Comment: Well I guess you could somehow parse the dependencies into a single package json file and then go over it using a script. Dunno if there’s a built in command for that

Comment: The npm client is open source. You can always open a pull request: https://github.com/npm/cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install packages in a safe way, then use `npm list` and `npm view` to get the age of install packages.

Option 1: install with `--ignore-scripts`

```sh
npm i --ignore-scripts
npm list --depth=100 | awk '{ print $NF }'| tail -n +2 | grep -v "deduped" |  xargs -I {}  bash -c "npm view {} time.modified _id|tr '\n' ' ' && echo "|sort
```

Option 2: install in docker

```sh
docker run -v $PWD/package.json:/a/package.json -v $PWD/package-lock.json:/a/package-lock.json --rm -it node:lts-buster bash

cd a && npm i
npm list --depth=100 | awk '{ print $NF }'| tail -n +2 | grep -v "deduped" |  xargs -I {}  bash -c "npm view {} time.modified _id|tr '\n' ' ' && echo "|sort
```

explanation of the script, that prints the dates:

- `npm list --depth=100` get list of installed packages
- `| awk '{ print $NF }'`extract the id of the package from each line
- `| tail -n +2` drop first line, which refers to the current folder
- `| grep -v "deduped"` remove lines which refer to dupes
- `|  xargs -I {} bash -c` for each line open subshell
- `npm view {} time.modified _id` get time and package-id
- `|tr '\n' ' ' && echo`  remove line break between time and id, and add linebreak at the end
- `|sort` sort lines alphabetically

note: since `npm view` fetches 1 package at a time via network, the script takes about 1s per installed packages, which will add up to a couple of minutes for medium-sized projects.

Answer (score 8):

To find out the malicious package, you will need a script that will check your package for vulnerabilities against [national vulnerabilities database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMBZm.png)

The National Vulnerability Database includes databases of security checklist references, security related software flaws, misconfigurations, product names, and impact metrics.

Mostly all software companies use application security tools like *Veracode*, *Snyk* or *Checkmarx* that does this usually in a stage before deployment in the CICD pipeline.

If you're looking to achieve this locally, you can try

```
npm audit
```

But this will audit the *installed* dependencies and *also* its sub-dependencies in your project against the default registry (*nexus or artifactory or npm registry*) and gets you the list of known vulnerabilities with the version details in which patch is available.

`npm view` will get you the below details about the package even when it is ***not installed***.

[image]

> version checks before installing would need a script to do the necessary at preinstall, I would suggest to
> have a dedicated project for security checks (reusable for all projects), and `link` or
> `publish` it then configure that in your project scripts like
> below,

**Security Project:**

This will have the script to check for vulnerabilities, leverage `npm view` or `npm version` and audit the module then return the results.

**Main project:**

In here setup the scripts in `package.json` to use the above published project and check for vulnerabilities before installation.

```
npx security-project vulnerabilities


scripts: {
  vulnerability: npx security-project vulnerabilities
  preinstall: npx security-project vulnerabilities

  or

  preinstall: "sh ./checkVulnerabilities.sh" // this script can take package name through command line flags like --package axios
}
```

**Snyk** takes your `package.json` and will scan all the modules for security vulnerabilities. You could also search for specific module and check for a version's health score.

https://snyk.io/advisor/check/npm

Alternatively, you could use [Snyk extension](https://snyk.io/ide-plugins/) in your IDE for the same.

We have [RetireJS chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retirejs/moibopkbhjceeedibkbkbchbjnkadmom?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) for scanning vulnerable JS module version with vulnerabilities in the application.

Good Ref:- [6-tools-you-can-use-to-check-for-vulnerabilities-in-node-js](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/6-tools-you-can-use-to-check-for-vulnerabilities-in-node-js/)

Above are the ideas that I could think of, hope it helps.

Comment: my question was aiming at the timeframe where a malicious version has been pushed, but not yet flagged as malicious. During that short time, I am completely helpless, so i am looking for something mitigate there. Your answer would help to shorten that time, but not eleminate it. Also I believe, when a version is intentionally malicious, than it would be pulled form NPM very soon after it has been reported to snyk etc.

Comment: @wotanii malicious versions are flagged and recorded by NVD. The dev would push a patch addressing the vulnerability and it is not pulled. "That short time" you're referring to, how will you know a version is malicious while it is not yet flagged so? npm view is the only way to view the package details before installing.

Comment: "how will you know a version is malicious while it is not yet flagged so?" exactly this!! I can't know. That's why I want to treat too new version as "potentially dangerous" and only install versions, that are old enough for security auditors to do their thing. That being said: your answer is the perfect canonical answer, even I it is not what I have been hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. Instead of updating directly with npm, I can use renovate instead, which has a "stabilityDays" options:

> If this is set to a non-zero value, and an update has a release timestamp header, then Renovate will check if the "stability days" have passed.

https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#stabilitydays